# The way of Laravel API usage

Tags: laravel-5

Hello laravel experts.

Laravel provides us lots of APIs.
For example.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
   public function showUserName()
   {
      return Auth::user()->name;
   }
}
```

As you can see using Auth Facades we can get user name easily without any database manipulation.

But I never found the explanation about the usages of other Facades or API functions.

Please let me know the links or seminar where can I learn about this.

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5

Comment: There are so many Laravel Facade classes but I've never seen the usages example of them.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to be a little more specific?

Comment: I saw this. https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Cache.html  There is no get() function. But Laravel tutorial shows us $user = Cache::get('user:'.$id); this code.

Comment: That's covered in the docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache#cache-usage

Comment: Yes, cache usage shows us it has get() function. but where can I find the cache's member function list?

Comment: If you view the facade source code, it tells you what classes it uses - https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Cache.php#L6. You're looking for the CacheManager and Repository.

Comment: It seems that you don't understand the Facade design pattern, rather than it being a problem with documentation.

Comment: Then how can we find the user() function in Auth facade?

Comment: Read this. It'll explain how Facades work - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/facades and the container bindings they use.

Comment: Have you got any other suggestion?

Comment: Any more suggestions for what? If you have read the docs, read the Laravel source code and have read up on the Facade design pattern, no. If you haven't, do that.